# Making sure that nothing interrupts simulation, when doing it overnight (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows-10, julia, simulation, interrupt

last night I was doing my first simulation that was supposed to take more time than usual programs. It was 1 000 000 steps of Monte Carlo in Ising model for several temperature configurations with generating animations all made in Julia language. I am using Windows 10 and I set my computer not to hibernate at all to avoid interruption. Despite, in the morning I faced that my computer was in hibernation mode and none of my simulations were made. I think the reason for this is that Windows made an automatic update that very night.

So that starts my question. Do you know some tricks to avoid situations like this, that an overnight simulation may be interrupted? I don't mean just the update thing - it is easy to manage but in this case I just forgot about it. Did you face some other problems in such long simulation in your programming expirience and have tricks how to avoid them? Or maybe do you have some ways to do such simulation in clouds (I have never tried this so it might be helpful too).

If answears depends on the languages that the code is written in, I could say that the most helpful for me would be tricks in python or julia, but all languages are welcome - maybe someone else will be interested.

Comment: My most effective trick was to stop using Windows :-)

Comment: Yes...I am thinking about switch to ubuntu but not for now. So you faced no similar problems on your platform?

Comment: To add to @ColinTBowers 's comment I also use a Linux distro for scientific computing... my Windows box is mainly for reports and presentations ;)

Comment: I use Ubuntu now for everything other than gaming and Zoom. I stream financial data in real time, often setting routines to run for 6 days straight (Sunday to Saturday). I've never had any problems doing this with Ubuntu, but with Windows it was an absolute nightmare.

Comment: How difficult would it be to integrate a way to interrupt/save work, and then continue later? This would help not only against random updates, but other things like power loss.

Comment: This is probably a better question for SuperUser; a [quick search](https://superuser.com/search?q=hibernation+prevent) there reveals [several](https://superuser.com/questions/276197/prevent-hibernation-windows-7-optiplex-780) [results](https://superuser.com/questions/902585/how-to-prevent-hibernation-during-work-hours) (although those are for Windows 7).

Comment: Use AWS cloud (or other) for that sort of computations. Regarding Windows, you need to have Windows Pro to be able to manage updates - if you have Win Home the case is lost

Comment: Thank you, that might be usefull

Comment: If you go for a Linux cloud/server, I can't avoid recommend the `screen` utility: it lets you run whatever you want.. detach, disconnet, and then go back to your server, re-attach the terminal, and go back where you were as you never left the terminal. An other tool for extra-simple parallelisation of long tasks: gnu `parallel`

Comment: @Antonello or `byobu` for a much friendlier interface of the same